# How to run Google Cloud Messaging in class and not in mainactivity

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging

I have a running example of sending messages to Google Cloud Messaging, but I have now multiple classes that need to handle sending messages to GCM.

So I want to move the classes from my mainactivity to a class named ConnectGCM.

I putted it in a Service so that I can start it when the mainactivity is called, but also when there is a location changed.

My ConnectGCM class looks like:

```
public class ConnectGcm extends Service {

    String SENDER_ID = "1062728725724";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;
    String regid;

    private static final String TAG = "GCMCONNECT";

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        regid = getRegistrationId(context);
        //regid = "";
        if (regid.isEmpty()) {
            registerInBackground();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void sendMessageToGCMAppServer() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    //create message
                    data.putString("my_message","my_data");
                   data.putString("my_action","com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW");
                    String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
                    gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
                    msg = "Data sended to GCM";

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                //mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    //Initialize GCM
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }
    private void registerInBackground() {

        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }

            private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
                final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
                int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
                Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
                editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

In my mainactivity I try to send data to GCM with the following functions.

```
    ConnectGcm connector_GCM;
    startService(new Intent(this, ConnectGcm.class));
    connector_GCM.sendMessageToGCMAppServer("");
```

But this is not a success. Anyone ideas how to get this working?

Comment: place ur startservice after sendMessageToGCMAppServer method call.And what are you passing as parameter to your method?

Comment: To the sendmessageToGCMAppServer? Some coordinates of my location and other data. But I made it now that it only sends data when I call the function. First calling send function and then service is not working.

Comment: Can find the exception log here : http://nl.tinypic.com/r/25fmxe0/8

Comment: You'll need to solve that null pointer issue first. Logs suggest the problem is in your `HomeActivity` line 98.